# Al compilar en Qt tengo un error de "g++"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Al compilar en Qt me aparece este error y no puedo ejecutar.

> **Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?** 15:22:23: The process
>   "C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 3. Error while
>   building/deploying project mapviewer (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MinGW
>   32bit) When executing step "qmake"

Comment: No encuentra el compilador... revisa la instalación a ver si se te ha pasado instalarlo... entra en la herramienta de mantenimiento y revisa la sección "tools"... ahí encontrarás el compilador mingw, para la versión 5.9.1 necesitas el más moderno

Comment: Si es eso avísame y lo pongo como respuesta

Comment: como se hace eso?

Comment: Abre la herramienta de mantenimiento de Qt (localízala en el menú inicio en la carpeta Qt), si te pide una cuenta presiona el botón _skip_ y después dile que quieres añadir o eliminar componentes... te aparecerá un arbol y ahí localizas la sección tools y seleccionas el compilador que toca

Comment: vale, gracias!!